# How to set Identity Specification YES in 2 columns in a table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, settings, identity

How to set Identity Specification YES in 2 columns in a table in SQL Server 2008 ?

**Example:**

```
id int, 
catid int,
```

for `"@id"` i am using primary key and i set Is Identity YES. allow not null.

for `"@catid"` i want to set Identity YES also,

but when i set Identity YES for `"@catid"` column,   `"@id"` column it becomes Identity No itself.

i want `@catid` also generate id itself like `@id`.

check picture attached plz. and suggest me

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If it were possible for both to be identity columns, they'd always have the same value (unless you set the start/increment differently, but in that case, one would always be calculable from the other).

Comment: I am making a blog in asp.net c#. 

no problem ok thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are having some table design issues. Why would you like to have two Identity columns? As stated in the comments, the values will always be either the same or be computable from the original identity specification:

```
create table MyTable (
    Id int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    CatId as Id, -- computed column
    MyField nvarchar(100) null
)
```

Yields:

```
Id  CatId   MyField
1   1       A
2   2       B
3   3       C
4   4       D
5   5       E
```

Now if we would like to have some different value for CatId:

```
create table MyTable (
    Id int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    CatId as Id * 3, -- some different value
    MyField nvarchar(100) null
)
```

We would get:

```
Id  CatId   MyField
1   3       A
2   6       B
3   9       C
4   12      D
5   15      E
```

Either way it never makes sense to have multiple identity columns.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for two columns to set identity in the same table but i have a way around

set your id to primary and identity and write a trigger on after insert operation on this table and then update the catid column with id values 
you will get id in two columns with one is primary key and other is normal column

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have more than one identity column. Instead make one column as primary key without auto increment.

Only one identity column allowed per table.

Make use of primary key.